# Input field get disabled inside div

Tags: reactjs

How can I disable all the input fields inside a div element in ReactJs.

I search it but most of them are not on react.

Can somebody help me in this please.

```
<div>
<input />
<div>
<input />
</div>
</div>
```

I want to make both the input inside div as disabled.

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: @itsanewabstract Done

Comment: That is not React code. Post your entire component please

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. If you have an input field like TextBox, you can disable it like this:

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    export default class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
        public render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <input className="e-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" disabled={true}/>
                    <div className="e-float-input e-disabled">
                        <input type='text' required = {true}  disabled = {true}/>
                        <span className="e-float-line"/>
                        <label className="e-float-text">Enter Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('input-container'));
```

Comment: Is `e-disabled` doing something?

Comment: I dont want to use `disabled = {true}` inside input tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` to place all your inputs into an initial disabled state.

Here's an example:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

    inputs.forEach((el) => el.disabled = true)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If your code is more complicated, you can replace the simple selector for `input` with whatever CSS selector works for you.